# Automatic generation of function stubs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stub

Is there any Visual Studio add-on (or windows/unix stand-alone program) that creates stub implementations in the cpp file for the functions (including class member functions) that are defined in the header file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem before and now I am using trial version of [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/). The task mentioned can be done by right clicking on the method name -> Refactor -> Create Implementation and then Refactor -> Move Implementation to CPP file.

I am no Visual Assist X's affiliate or what, but this really increases my coding speed with Visual C++ dramatically.

Comment: We use Visual Assist where I work and it does offer a lot of handy features like this.  But, once your trial expires, it is not cheap, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

[Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/) works with Dev Studio 2005 and 2008.  The free version "kind-of" let's you do this; if you type your stub method in your header file (by typing something like `void Foo(int bar){}` instead of `void Foo(int bar);`) you can then "Move method to source file."

The full version has many more features but I'm not familiar with their usage.

Comment: Never know of this tool before. Maybe I will give it a try too.