# Doxygen Automatic Stub Generation

Tags: doxygen

I am curious if doxygen itself can be used to automatically add doxygen comment stubs to my partially documented C++ project.

I use the DoxygenToolkit in vim, but :Dox above each function in a rather large project is rather taxing. I'd rather spend that energy actually writing documentation.

I am *not* asking about a plugin to an IDE for newly written code, such as:

[Automatic generation of function stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402824/automatic-generation-of-function-stubs)

but massive amounts of preexisting code.

Comment: i should say, that doxygen obviously already sees undocumented code and generates empty documentation in the HTML/XML etc for it, I am asking if it can stick the appropriate empty  stub just above each function so then I can go fill it in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Doxygen cannot modify your source. This is an editor feature.

Comment: Is there a script around that does this?