# Automatic doxygen documentation for pre-existing fortran 90 code

Tags: python, emacs, fortran, doxygen, fortran90

My question is related to this one, I guess : [Doxygen Automatic Stub Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687247/doxygen-automatic-stub-generation)

So, I have to work with a relative big project written in Fortran 90, with little to no comments. And I was asked to add Doxygen documentation for many of these files, mainly, many functions definitions. So I started coding the project but it seems like a lot of time will be wasted on a couple of things that can be generated automatically.

For example, I have a file Test.f90 with many functions of the type:

```
function some_function( arg1, arg2, arg3) result(res)
    integer, intent(in) :: arg1, arg2
    mytype,  intent(in) :: arg3
    integer             :: arg4
    float               :: res
    !.... some code ....
end function some_function
```

and I want to obtain something pre-commented so that I can just fill in the actual comments, like this :

```
  !-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  !> @brief 
  !> @details 
  !> @param[in] arg1 integer  
  !> @param[in] arg2 integer  
  !> @param[in] arg3 mytype  
  !> @param[out] res float
    function some_function( arg1, arg2, arg3) result(res)
        integer, intent(in) :: arg1, arg2
        mytype,  intent(in) :: arg3
        integer             :: arg4
        float               :: res
        !.... some code ....
    end function some_function
```

I usually use emacs to code, and I was only available to find [Doxymacs](http://doxymacs.sourceforge.net/) but it's only for C and C++.

So I guess my questions now are :

1. Did I miss any emacs plugin that will allow me to do such an automatization ?
2. If I didn't, is there any (Python) script that will allow me to pass a F90 file and that will generate the code blocks ?

Thanks for any help you can give me !

Comment: The types do not look like Fortran.

Comment: It's just an example

Comment: If you attach the comments for the arguments to the arguments themselves, then there's no need for the @param[xx] line.  The first sentence of a description can be automatically used as the brief description and the body used as the details (and perhaps that's by default) - so the only thing you actually need to add automatically is the `!----` comment line...

Comment: It may be better to use valid Fortran code in the example (note also that `intent(out)` is wrong for the result `res`): my experience has been that for Fortran code with, say, `integer, intent(in) :: arg1 !< Best variable ever` all I desired has been detected.

Comment: That could actually save me a lot of time ! Thanks ! Unfortunately whoever coded the files didn't respect the rule of one-argument-one-line. That's why I put `arg1` and `arg2` on the same line, as the solution should support this. Anyhow, for the moment I will use your solution, thank you !

Comment: PS: I took out the `intent (out)`, it is indeed false.